# How to call nth next value in dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm sorry that I cannot explain exactly. So, I'll ask with simple example.
While I'm looking at [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69023354/defining-element-based-on-condition-in-r/69023417#69023417) I use `for` loop to replace `yes` value to `N/A`.

```
stim <- c("a", "k", "y", "j", "t", "Stop", "f", "l", "b", "a", "c", "Stop")
df <- data.frame(stim)

df<- df%>%
  mutate(YesorNo = ifelse(stim == "Stop", "N/A", "yes"))
for (i in 1:dim(df)[1]){
  if (df$YesorNo[i] == "N/A") {
    if(i == 1){
    } else {
      df$YesorNo[i-1] = "no"
    }
  }
}
```

In `for` loop above, how can I call that `YesorNo[i-1]` in `dplyr`?

Similarly, for a fixed number `n`, how to call `YesorNo[i-n]`?

Comment: `lag(YesorNo, n)` gives you nth previous value whereas `lead` will give you next value.

Comment: The function you are looking for is `lag()`

Comment: @RonakShah @Sotos Thanks a lot! From `lag()` I found `lead()` to go backward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `lag` and `lead` functions in `dplyr`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(previous_value = lag(stim), 
         next_value = lead(stim))

#   stim previous_value next_value
#1     a           <NA>          k
#2     k              a          y
#3     y              k          j
#4     j              y          t
#5     t              j       Stop
#6  Stop              t          f
#7     f           Stop          l
#8     l              f          b
#9     b              l          a
#10    a              b          c
#11    c              a       Stop
#12 Stop              c       <NA>
```

Note that default first and last value for `lag` and `lead` function is `NA` respectively.

In `data.table` the equivalent function is `shift` -

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)
df[, previous_value := shift(stim, type = 'lag')]
df[, next_value := shift(stim, type = 'lead')]
```